# Symfony doctrine group by max date timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, group-by

I would like to select values from table o by some conditions and grouped by groupKey. This query is working fine, but now query return first grouped value for my. I need to retrieve grouped values with MAX timestamp.

An example if there are two or more values with groupKey I need that one where o.createdAt value is newer.

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('order');
    $expr = $qb->expr();

    return $qb
        ->select('order, (CASE WHEN order.tsmOrderNumber IS NOT NULL THEN order.tsmOrderNumber ELSE order.id END) as groupKey')
        ->where('order.user =:user')
        ->andWhere('order.status =:status')
        ->andWhere(
            $expr->orX(
                $expr->andX(
                    $expr->isNotNull('order.wayBillNumber'),
                    $expr->neq('order.wayBillNumber', "''"),
                    $expr->between('order.createdAt', ':dateFrom', ':dateTo')
                ),
                $expr->andX(
                    $expr->orX(
                        $expr->isNull('o.tsmNumber'),
                        $expr->eq('o.tsmNumber', '\'\'')
                    ),
                    $expr->between('order.createdAt', ':dateFrom2', ':dateTo')
                )
            )
        )
        ->setParameters(
            [
                'status'    => Order::STATUS_COMPLETED,
                'user'      => $user,
                'dateFrom'  => (new \DateTime())->modify('-2 month'),
                'dateFrom2' => (new \DateTime())->modify('-6 month'),
                'dateTo'    => new \DateTime()
            ]
        )
        ->groupBy('groupKey')
        ->orderBy('order.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Please use longer, meaningful aliases for your entities in Query Builder.

Comment: If you are working on this with a team, they may not like supporting this code. Would not it by cleaner and easier to do with SQL?

Comment: Yes you're right code is not clear enough I already fixed it, but problem still exists.

Comment: @aurimas535 Can you post the plain SQL you want to convert to equivalent DQL ?